# Converting GHUnitTests to XCTest - replacement for GHTestLog

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, gh-unit, xctest

I'm converting a project to the XCTest framework, and am trying to find a good replacement for GHTestLog. I could easily change them to `XCTAssert(NO, @"...");` but this doesn't seem that elegant, because GHTestLog was never making an assertion. Is there a better way to replicate the functionality?